# Verify correctness of this PDA

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to construct a PDA for the language $\{a,b\}$ where there are the same number of $a$'s as $b$'s. This is what I have, but I'm skeptical on the correctness. Can anyone verify?

[image: picture]